# El método .equals("[0-9]{7,8}[A-Za-z]") no me da la salida esperada con esta expresión regular

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente método que me devuelve false cuando le paso una cadena entre 7 y 8 dígitos numéricos más una letra al final.

```
public boolean verificarDNI(String dni) {
    if (dni.equals("[0-9]{7,8}[A-Za-z]")){
        this.dni=dni;
        return true;            
    } else {
        return false;       
    }
}
```

Lo que pretendo es que me devuelva true cuando le paso una cadena con las condiciones de arriba. Una cadena de 7 a 8 dígitos númericos mas una letra.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias por las indicaciones.

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo es un simple comparacion de dos cadenas y no el resultado de una evaluación de expresión regular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El método `equals()` es para comparar con otro objeto del mismo tipo, para conseguir lo que buscas, utiliza `matches()`:

```
public boolean verificarDNI(String dni) {
    return dni.matches("[0-9]{7,8}[A-Za-z]");
}
```

Para más información sobre ambos métodos:

- JavaDoc de `String.matches()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-
- JavaDoc de `Object.equals()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-